# How to set Dutch Language in Text-To-Speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-location

I want to set Dutch Language in my TTS object. Following is the code,

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) 
{
    if ( status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS ) 
    {
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

        System.out.println ( "Result : " + result  + " " + Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() );

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) 
        {
            Toast.makeText( this , "Please Set your Language to English US.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
        else
        {
            tts.speak( "Hoe gaat het",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null );
        }
    }
}
```

Following line sets the language in TTS

```
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
```

Available Locale's in Locale.

> [image]

Now if my Phone's Language's is Dutch then I am able to set TTS's language as Dutch Language, but if My Phone's Language is not dutch ( for e.g. if it is English ) then there is no option to set the TTS's language as Dutch.

Can anybody help me to set the Dutch language in TTS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work

```
int result = tts.setLanguage(new Locale("nl_NL"));
```

Comment: Why on earth does dutch have the "de" prefix as in "Deutschland" instead of "nl" ??

Comment: Just for people who are looking into this, you need to change the prefix "de_NL" to "nl_NL" to get correct dutch

Answer (score 5):

You are setting default Locale in `setLocale`. That's the reason of this issue: *Now if my Phone's Language's is Dutch then I am able to set TTS's language as Dutch Language, but if My Phone's Language is not dutch ( for e.g. if it is English ) then there is no option to set the TTS's language as Dutch.*

You should use Locale you need instead. So replace

```
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
```

with

```
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.XYZ);  //XYZ is Locale you want.
```

Example:

```
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);
```

Refer[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html), which includes available Locales, which you can set. DUTCH is not available there.

Though [this](http://www.apps4android.org/?p=3695) article mentions that DUTCH is available Locale. May be it is not for android, but for java, as suggested [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-locale-list-tutorial/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check the question again, I have added image of available options in Locale.

Comment: Question specifically was around Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

for hindi-india

newsReaderTTS.setLanguage(new Locale("hin", "IND", "variant"));

for english usa

newsReaderTTS.setLanguage(new Locale("eng", "USA", "variant"));

where newsreaderTTS is TTS.